# how to install theme using connect manager in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento

hello everyone i want to install new theme in magento. I installed magento ver 1.7.0.2 & disabled all cache system->tools->cache management.

Now uploading theme via magentoconnect manager option '`Direct package file upload`'. I uploaded `package.xml` file from theme and clicked upload. But it gives a `***error` in command prompt like '`Please check the output frame for errors and refresh the page to retry changes.`'*** I don't know what does it mean. Can anyone please help me to sort the error.

Comment: Please copy paste the errors from console to this question.So some on will be able to help.